# Routing between places with mapbox or similar direction api

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, geojson

I have a geoJSON objects and I want to route between waypoints on my geoJSON file.

```
{
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "generator":"JOSM",
    "bbox":[
        23.4668,
        58.9198,
        23.6412,
        58.974
    ],
    "features":[

    {
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{
                "wheelchair":"yes",
                "smoothness":"bad",
                "surface":"crushed stones"
            },
            "geometry":{
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[
                    23.53359252,
                    58.95034587858
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{
                "wheelchair":"yes",
                "addr:housename":"Saue kohvik",
                "amenity":"pub",
                "name":"Saue kohvik"
            },
            "geometry":{
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[
                    23.5361382,
                    58.9473236
                ]
            }
        },
         {
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{
                "wheelchair":"yes",
                "smoothness":"intermediate",
                "highway":"footway"
            },
            "geometry":{
                "type":"LineString",
                "coordinates":[
                    [
                        23.5410658,
                        58.9406213
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5410936,
                        58.9408252
                    ],
                    [
                        23.541092,
                        58.9408358
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5410706,
                        58.9410896
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5410448,
                        58.9412609
                    ],
                    [
                        23.541028,
                        58.9413309
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5409993,
                        58.9414512
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5408984,
                        58.9416477
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5408677,
                        58.9416962
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5407571,
                        58.9418706
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5405886,
                        58.9421204
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5405302,
                        58.9422071
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5403894,
                        58.9423888
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5401636,
                        58.9426413
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5400953,
                        58.9426593
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5399336,
                        58.9428447
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5399287,
                        58.9428504
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5399434,
                        58.9428895
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5394702,
                        58.9434341
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5394296,
                        58.943468
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5389324,
                        58.9439879
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5384256,
                        58.9445103
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5381597,
                        58.9447992
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5377425,
                        58.9452314
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5375449,
                        58.9454551
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
         {
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties":{
                "wheelchair":"yes",
                "highway":"footway"
            },
            "geometry":{
                "type":"LineString",
                "coordinates":[
                    [
                        23.5408677,
                        58.9416962
                    ],
                    [
                        23.541045,
                        58.9417267
                    ],
                    [
                        23.5412157,
                        58.9417564
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }

        ]
}
```

And my question is: Can I route between places inside my file "routing only on these LineStrings where properties are "wheelchair":"yes"and "highway":"footway". And routing cant use LineStrings where property is only "highway":"footway".

Is it possible when I'm using mapbox direction service?

I made my own openstreetmap with my custom properties, but know I'm stuck, I don't know how do route in that map, because routing can only call out on these ways (linestrings and points) where one property is wheelchair="yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `L.mapbox.FeatureLayer` to render your featurecollection in combination with a filter:

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer('data.geo.json').addTo(map);

var filter = function (feature) {
  // Check if feature is a linestring
  if (feature.geometry.type == 'Linestring') {
    // Check if has property wheelchair and value is yes
    if (feature.properties.hasOwnProperty('wheelchair') &&
        feature.properties.wheelchair === 'yes') {
      // Check if has property highway and value is footway
      if (!feature.properties.hasOwnProperty('highway') || 
          feature.properties.highway === 'footway') {
          // highway absent or highway is footway
          return true;
      } else {
        // highway found and value is not footway
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      // Wheelchair absent or value isn't yes
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    // Not a linestring
    return true;
  }
}

featureLayer.on('ready', function () {
  featureLayer.setFilter(filter);
});
```

Reference for `L.mapbox.featureLayer`: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.5/l-mapbox-featurelayer/

Comment: okey TNX, ist helpful, but can you tell me, if i have added my Data to map, then how do navigate on my data?

Comment: You would need to write your own logic which, if i'm frank, is a monumental task. There is out-of-the-box no such thing in Mapbox at the moment  (As far as i know) It's in the works, you can take a look here: https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/directions/ and apply for testing if you like.

Comment: okey , but do you know any other frameworks or api-s where that is possible?

Comment: You could take a look at https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine  that's opensource. But i don't have a clue if it can do what you need because i haven't used it myself.

Comment: iH8 tnx for that information and you were correct, they doesnt have a method to limit my walking directions to wheelchair="yes" paths, but i made a issue and maybe they add that feature now :)